# How to re-order list items added by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I found here by searching a good way to re-order list items.

```
$(".reOrder li").click(function() {
       var index = $(".reOrder li").index(this);
       if (index != 0) {
          // li item is not sitting in the first position
          $(".reOrder li:eq(" + (index - 1) + ")").before(this);
       }
       });
```

The problem is, I have LI items that I have added to the UL via jQuery's append method, and the clicks don't seem to be registered for those. [Here's a simplified fiddle showing what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/8vWXZ/149/).  Note how the original list items work fine, but if you add one, clicking on that has no effect.

I have even tried a simple click alert, so it's not getting the click event. How do I need to change my code to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're example code uses a class, and in the fiddle, it's an ID, but I guess you know that.

An event handler, like the one in your code, only works on elements that are present on the page at the time the events are bound. When adding elements, those would be dynamic, and you would you need a delegated event handler, where the event is bound to a non-dynamic parent, and checks for the second selector, in this case `li` :

```
$(".reOrder").on('click', 'li', function() {
     var index = $(".reOrder li").index(this);
     if (index != 0) {
        // li item is not sitting in the first position
        $(".reOrder li:eq(" + (index - 1) + ")").before(this);
     }
});
```

This won't work in jQuery 1.4, which is the version used in you fiddle, and you should upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: +1. Everything correct except for "only works on elements that are present on the page at the time the events are bound." The events are bound only to the set of matched elements. So when you append new elements after selecting the `li` elements, they obviously don't get the event listener.

Comment: @Derija93 - Uhm, that would make it so that event handlers only works for elements that are present at the time of binding, as you can't select elements that are'nt there. It's impossible to bind events to elements that does'nt exist yet, delegated event handlers bind to parent elements to circumvent this.

Comment: That makes sense, but if you try the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/8vWXZ/154/ something must be wrong, since now nothing works, including my add button.

EDIT:  just saw your edit about the jquery version.  Of course.  I used someone's old fiddle. I am using 1.8.3 and it does indeed work.  Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo How would I modify that selector to select a child of the generated LI (such as an A tag)?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, there's no doubt to that. I just wanted to clarify that it's not strictly binding events to all elements currently present at binding time, but to those selected. Altering the set of matched elements with `.not` or `.add` excludes and/or includes particular elements. That's all I'm saying, using delegates is still the correct way.

Comment: @Steve - `$(".reOrder").on('click', 'li a', function() { ...`

Comment: @Derija93 - Ah, I see, it would be a bitch if it added the click event to all elements currently on the page, and not only those selected by the selector.

Comment: @adeneo Indeed. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough in my first comment.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks.  I figured that, but I'm unsure how to change the rest so the index of the LI is still used, and it's the LI that is moved.  If you see my updated fiddle you'll see the B tag gets moved not the LI.  http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/8vWXZ/158/

Answer (score 1):

As per the jQuery documentation

[> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

And also to respect the version of jQuery you are using on the fiddle (1.4.2 doesn't have .on() anyway). Best would be to use delegate

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

as per the jQuery documentation

> Deletegate() Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for
>   all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a
>   specific set of root elements.

or you could try instead of attaching to the click event of the li items, attach to the parent ul (which is always there) and then test the target (i.e. which li was clicked)